# Symfony 2: Way to store app configuration for templates and controller

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony and looking for a way store (and read) some informations, which I want to use in controller and templates.

Basically I want to access this sample structure:

```
project:
    name: "My cool Project"
cdn: "http://www.example.com"
paths: 
    "images": "/images",
    "pdf": "/pdf"
...
```

**I have already tried to add this to my parameters.yml. But is it the correct place and how to access it in template AND controller?**

In controller, I can do:

```
$this->getParameter("project")
```

Is there a way to directly access project.name? Something like:

```
$this->getParameter("project.name")
```

How to access it in template?

Comment: parameter.yml is really for information that changes based on the host.  Things like database passwords. If your information is the same between production and development then I would suggest making a new parameter file such as project.yml and loading the file by editing config.yml.  That avoids cluttering up your parameters.yml with stuff that probably does not change much.

Comment: And take a look at the bundles and configuration chapters in the cookbook: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/index.html It can be a little be tough to get started but there a lot of power in configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the parameter from the controller to the view:

In the controller class:

```
return [
    'variable' => $this->getContainer()->getParameter('variable');
];
```

In the twig template, to print it:

```
{{ variable }}
```

If you want to pass a parameter to the templates without passing it in every controller, use the `twig.globals` configuration:

```
twig:
    globals:
        variable: %variable%
```

Then print it the same way as above.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, I would have to pass the parameter in every controller to the template. For example the "cdn" value is used in the base layout template.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getParameter('project')['name'];
```

EDIT:

For the view, have a look to global Variables in Twig:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I was looking for a nice way. But how to access it in template and is parameters.yml the best place for storing such informations?